# whateverorigin run html code

Tags: javascript, same-origin-policy

I'm trying to run a small application in an `iframe` using whatever origin:

```
    <script>
    $.getJSON('http://whateverorigin.org/get?url=' +      
    encodeURIComponent('http://vend.giftcardservices.nl/saldo/3') + 
    '&callback=?', function(data){
    alert(data.contents);
    });
    </script>
```

And the alert shows the html is fetched, but when I try to `document.write(data.contents)`, nothing is happening. How do I get this code to be executed in the browser?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're using jQuery already, [don't use `document.write`](https://stackoverflow.com/q/802854/2151050). Instead, use

```
$(document.body).append(data.content);
```

And if you're loading the content into a specific element, you could use

```
$('#selector').html(data.content);
```

Here's the snippet

```js
$.getJSON('http://whateverorigin.org/get?url=' +      
    encodeURIComponent('http://vend.giftcardservices.nl/saldo/3') + 
    '&callback=?', function(data){
    $(document.body).append(data.contents.replace('/static/js/saldo.js', 'http://vend.giftcardservices.nl/saldo/3/static/js/saldo.js'));
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.0.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: This however does come with the effect that the functionality of the widget doesn't work anymore - url not found. Any idea for a solution for that?

Comment: Hmmm, use the iframe then, they allow CORS.

Comment: Ahh, ok. Thanks anyway.